# How to remove mentioned characters from network stream string

Tags: c#, html, webforms, telnet, tcpclient

I am doing telnet from a web page using TcpClient

```
server = new TcpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DynamicIP"], Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DynamicPort"]));
            ns = server.GetStream();
```

While reading response of a stream with below method.

```
if (ns.CanRead)
        {
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
            int numBytesRead = 0;
            do
            {
                numBytesRead = ns.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
                // ss= Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(readBuffer.ToArray());
                //sb.Append(readBuffer[0].ToString);
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBuffer, 0, numBytesRead));
                sb.Replace(Convert.ToChar(24), ' ');
                sb.Replace(Convert.ToChar(255), ' ');
                sb.Replace('?', ' ');
                //sb.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />").ToString();
            }
            while (ns.DataAvailable);
        }
        // var s = Regex.Replace(sb.ToString(), @"[^\u0000-\u007F]", string.Empty);
        //var s = "<br/>" + sb.ToString();
        //s = s.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
        //var chars = s.Where(c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark).ToArray();
        //return new string(chars).Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
        ////return "<br/>" + s.ToString();
        var dd = "<br/>" + sb.ToString();
        return dd;
```

but string contains the below characters in it. How to remove or replace in order to show the telnet response in readable format in web form? I have tried so many things, but in vain.

I would like to show the response in webpage just like Putty reads the response.

Thanks in advance.

> ;40f;9f;40f;9f;40f;2f;40f;9f[4;34f;9f[4;37f;2f[4;34f;9f[4;34f;11f;40f;9f;40f;9f;40f;11f[4;39f;9f[4;34f;11f[4;37f;9f[4;34f;9f[4;37f;40f[4;34f;40f;9f;40f;11f;40f;11f;40f;9f[4;37f;9f[4;37f;9f[4;37f;11f[4;34f;9f[4;34f;40f[4;34f;40f;11f;40f;11f;40f;11f;40f;9f[4;39f;2f[4;34f;9f[4;37f;9f[4;34f;40f[4;37f;40f;9f;40f;9f;40f;9f;40f;11f[4;37f;9f[4;37f;11f[4;37f;9f[4;34f;40f[4;37f;40f[4;37f;40f;9f;40f;2f;40f;9f[4;37f;9f[4;37f;11f[4;37f;11f[4;39f;9f[4;37f;40f;9f;40f;9f;40f;11f;40f;9f;40f;9f[4;34f;2f[4;34f;9f[4;37f;11f[4;34f;40f[4;37f;40f[4;34f;40f"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your telnet server assumes you support [ANSI/VT100](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm). Because that is what all those characters are. For example (`<ESC>` indicates the charater with [ascii value 27](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII))

> `<ESC>[4;34f`

is the ANSI control sequence for Force Cursor Position `<ESC>[{ROW};{COLUMN}f`.

You either have to convince your telnet server that you don't support ANSI/VT100 or write a parser that can handle the ANSI/VT100 control codes.

For now I did the latter. A naive parser might look like this. It doesn't do anything, except parsing out the ANSI/VT100 codes and doesn't append those to the StringBuilder.

```
var ns = server.GetStream();
// keep state of the parser
bool Ansi = false;
bool AnsiSub = false;
bool InFirstNumber = false;
bool InSecondNumber = false;
string firstnumber = String.Empty;
string secondnumber = String.Empty;

if (ns.CanRead)
{
    // testcase
    // var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("foo\x1b[123A\x1b[123;456ftest2\x1bKblah\x1b[s"));
    var sr = new StreamReader(ns, Encoding.ASCII);
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        var chr = sr.Read();
        switch (chr)
        {
            case 27:
                // escape char means next chars will be ANSI code
                Ansi = true;
                break;
            default:
                if (Ansi)
                {
                    // will this be a single ANSI code char or multiple
                    if (!AnsiSub)
                    {
                        switch ((char)chr)
                        {
                            case '[':
                                // multiple, set state 
                                AnsiSub = true;
                                InFirstNumber = true;
                                InSecondNumber = false;
                                firstnumber = string.Empty;
                                secondnumber = string.Empty;
                                break;
                            default:
                                // handle this char if needed
                                // possible is: 78()DMH
                                Ansi = false;
                                AnsiSub = false;
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var achar = (char)chr;
                        // number checks and capturing
                        if (Char.IsDigit(achar))
                        {
                            // a bit sloppy
                            if (InFirstNumber)
                            {
                                firstnumber += achar;
                            } 
                            else
                            {
                                // HACK, refactor later
                                if (InSecondNumber)
                                {
                                    secondnumber += achar;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (achar == ';')
                            {
                                // number sequence break
                                InSecondNumber = true;
                                InFirstNumber = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // last char of ANSI code
                                switch (achar)
                                {
                                    case 'A':
                                        // Cursor Up        <ESC>[{COUNT}A
                                        break;
                                    case 'f':
                                        // Force Cursor Position    <ESC>[{ROW};{COLUMN}f
                                        Console.WriteLine("Force cursor row:{0}, col:{1}", firstnumber, secondnumber);
                                        break;
                                }
                                // now we are done, reset state
                                Ansi = false;
                                AnsiSub = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
                else
                {
                    // plain character
                    sb.Append((Char)chr);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Notice that I used a [`StreamReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456(v=vs.110).aspx) to read the networkstream. StreamReader comes with an overload in its constructor that accepts an Encoding. That prevents that you have to deal with decoding bytes from the stream yourself, which was definitely broken in your code. You can't safely decode partial bytebuffers.